# How to remove NSUserNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsusernotificationcenter

I am using NSUserNotificationCenter to display scheduled Notifications. I have notifications of my app in the right side notification panel so whenever I click on the notification it'll launch the app but it won't remove notification from the panel.

1. When app is not running and I clicked on the notification, applicationDidFinishLaunching is called and it won't remove notification because didActivateNotification delegate is not called.
2. When application is already running and I clicked on the notification, appShouldHandleReopen is called. And won't call the delegate.

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(id)center didActivateNotification:(id)notification

I checked behavior in all the standard app they will remove notification when user click on the notifications.

I have implemented it as follows:

```
/* will create notification and set the delegate*/
@interface NotificationViewController : NSViewController
{
id delegate;
}
-(void)showNotification;
@end

@implementation NotificationViewController
- (void)createNotification:(NSString*)str
{

    Class UserNotificationClass=NSClassFromString(@"NSUserNotification");
    id notification = [[UserNotificationClass alloc] init];
    //Set the title of the notification
    [notification setTitle:@"My Notification"];
    [notification setSubtitle:@"Test"];
    [notification setHasActionButton:YES];
    [notification setActionButtonTitle:@"OK"];
    [notification setOtherButtonTitle:@"CANCEL"];

    //Set the text of the notification
    [notification setInformativeText:str];
    [notification setDeliveryDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0.1 sinceDate:[NSDate date]]];
    [notification setSoundName:@"NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName"];
    [notification setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:str,@"string",nil]];

    Class UserNotificationCenterClass=NSClassFromString(@"NSUserNotificationCenter");
    id center = [UserNotificationCenterClass defaultUserNotificationCenter];
    [center setDelegate:self.delegate];

    //Scheldule our NSUserNotification
    [center scheduleNotification:notification];
    [notification release];
}
@end

/* Class which implements NSUserNotificationDelegate*/

@interface NotificationHandler : NSObject <NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
{

}
- (void)createNotification:(NSString*)str;
@end


@implementation NotificationHandler
- (void)createNotification:(NSString*)str
{
NotificationHandler *notificationHandler = [[NotificationHandler alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationHandler" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        notificationHandler.delegate = self;
[notificationHandler showNotification];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(id)center didActivateNotification:(id)notification
{
    [center removeDeliveredNotification:notification];
}

- (BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(id)center shouldPresentNotification:(id)notification
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

However this is not working in my case. Please let me know some pointer on it...

**Other thing I observed:**

- When I implement NSUserNotificationDelegate into AppDelegate it'll work for 2nd case i.e. (When application is already running and I clicked on the notification) - in this case notification is removed.
- And for deleting notification for 1st case i.e. (When app is not running and I clicked on the notification, appDidFinishLaunching is called) I wrote following code in appDidFinishLaunching.

  NSUserNotification *userNoti = [[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"NSApplicationLaunchUserNotificationKey"];
  [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotification:userNoti];

  - Can anybody let me know whats the reason, why this works in the AppDelegate but not in my above implementation or Am I doing something wrong in first one?
  - Is my AppDelegate implementation fine to handle my both scenarios?

Thanks in Advance.